# What is a pseudo-Kähler manifold?

Tags: symplectic-geometry, connections, kahler-manifolds

I am reading [a text](http://homepages.warwick.ac.uk/~marke/research/files/ghent-v2.pdf) which says that if a symplectic manifold is pseudo-Kähler, then there exists a unique symplectic connection on it. Since this a side remark without significance to the core of that text, no definition of "pseudo-Kähler manifold" is given.

I've searched the internet, but I haven't found anything clear. Wikipedia mentions "nearly Kähler manifolds" and "almost Kähler manifolds", and some research papers mention "nearly pseudo-Kähler manifolds" and "generalized pseudo-Kähler structures", but none *pseudo-Kähler manifolds*.

What is, then, a pseudo-Kähler manifold? What are the prototypical examples?

Comment: I have never seen this term either, but Kahler manifold is a manifold with complex structure $J$ which is parallel in regard with the metric connection. On the other hand pseudo Riemannian manifold is a manifold with metric that could have any signature.

Comment: Pseudo-Riemannian Geometry, δ-Invariants and Applications
 By Bang-Yen Chen which you can see some of via Google books has a whole chapter on pseudo-Kähler manifolds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A *pseudo-Riemannian metric* on a manifold $M$ is a section $g \in \Gamma(M, S^2(T^*M))$ such that for each $p \in M$, $g_p \in \Gamma(M, S^2(T^*M))$ is non-degenerate. That is, if we view $g_p$ as a symmetric bilinear pairing $g_p : T_pM\times T_pM \to \mathbb{R}$, $g_p(X, Y) = 0$ for all $Y \in T_pM$ if and only if $X = 0$.

Now suppose $M$ is a complex manifold with corresponding almost complex structure $J$. A pseudo-Riemannian metric $g$ on $M$ is called *pseudo-hermitian* if $g(JX, JY) = g(X, Y)$. If in addition, the two-form $\omega(X, Y) = g(JX, Y)$ is closed (i.e. $d\omega = 0$), $g$ is called a *pseudo-Kähler* metric.

Note, as a Riemannian metric is a pseudo-Riemannian metric, every Kähler metric is a pseudo-Kähler metric.

Comment: 1) Why do you suppose $M$ to have a complex structure? It seems that you are using only its almost-complex properties. 2) Getting back to the text that motivated the question, if I say that a symplectic manifold $(M, \Omega)$ is also pseudo-Kähler, does it mean that $\Omega (X, Y) = g(JX, Y)$ (i.e. are the two structures supposed to be compatible?) 3) Could you please give me a non-trivial example of prototypical symplectic pseudo-Kähler manifolds? Are cotangent bundles, for instance, naturally such manifolds?

Comment: 1) If $J$ is not integrable, you get a pseudo-almost Kähler manifold, not a pseudo-Kähler manifold. 2) That's correct. 3) For examples, I second Grumpy Parsnip's book recommendation which can be seen on [Google books](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=Bim7CgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA202&ots=6fbMxiyPrO&dq=pseudo-K%C3%A4hler%20manifolds&pg=PA183#v=onepage&q&f=false).